# Уважаемые сотрудники Корпорации!

Tags: грамматика

> Здравствуйте!
>
> Уважаемые сотрудники Корпорации!
>
> Согласно пункту 3 подпункты 2 и 7 Правил внутреннего трудового распорядка Корпорации, прошу всех соблюдать трудовую дисциплину. На следующей неделе, прошу явку на рабочих местах вовремя. У кого есть встречи, прошу их записываться в журнале. Иначе этих сотрудников будем зафиксировать, как отсутствующих на рабочем месте. В случае нарушение настоящих Правил к сотруднику будут применяться строгие меры или  дисциплинарные взыскания в соответствии с  «Законом о труде Республики Казахстан» и Правилам внутреннего трудового распорядка.

Answer (score 1):

А что тут сделать надо?
Грамматика, конечно, оставляет желать...
Это школьное задание или в Казахстане так пишут?!

Если править только очевидные ощибки, не редактируя, то так:

Уважаемые сотрудники Корпорации!
         Согласно пункту 3 подпункт**ам** 2 и 7 Правил внутреннего трудового *распорядка Корпорации* прошу всех соблюдать трудовую дисциплину. На следующей неделе **прошу явиться на рабочие места вовремя**. **Тех,** у кого есть встречи, **прошу записать их** в журнале. Иначе эти сотрудники будут считаться отсутствующими на рабочем месте. В случае нарушения настоящих Правил(**?**) к сотруднику будут применяться строгие меры или  дисциплинарные взыскания в соответствии с «Законом о труде Республики Казахстан»(**??**) и Правилам внутреннего трудового распорядка.

(*?*) Что за правила? Если подразумевается приведенный текст, то это максимум распоряжение.
(**?**) Закон "О труде" и "Закон о труде" - как официально назыается?